# how to set the max text limit in jcombobox using netbeans

Tags: java, swing

Im using netbeans and I would like to know, how to set the max text limit that can be displayed in swing jcombobox

I have checked the properties window for the jcombobox, but I could not find any property for setting the text limit.

Any help on this is much appreciated.

Comment: when you set the text for jcombobox?

Comment: Thanks for the response. at times,the user also types in  some data in the jcombo box,my question is , how do I limit the number of characters that the user can enter in jcombo box.

Comment: can you share your codes?i assume you have a method for adding text to a jcombobox so you can control/limit length easily.check the length and do something

Answer (score 1):

> how do I limit the number of characters that the user can enter in jcombo box.

You can add a `DocumentFilter` to the editor of the combo box:

```
ComboBoxEditor editor = comboBox.getEditor();
JTextField textField = (JTextField)editor.getEditorComponent();
AbstractDocument doc = (AbstractDocument)textField.getDocument();
doc.setDocumentFilter( ...);
```

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Implementing a DocumentFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter) for an example filter the limits the number of characters that can be entered.